# i want to check already applied leave dates

Tags: mysql, linq

my table structure is as follows:

```
empid      leavefrom        leaveto  
  1        11/3/2014        12/3/2014
  1        25/3/2014        26/3/2014   
  1        27/3/2014        28/3/2014
  1        19/3/2014        21/3/2014
```

this all dates are those leave dates on whose employee have already taken leave or has applied leave.
my query is now if employee again apply for leave like on 20/3/2014-20/3/2014 then i want to generate error 
meassage because 20/3/2014 is already there is table in last record in above table.

i want linq query to solve this problem.please guys help me.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Any new leave with `startDate <= existing endate` AND `endate > existing startdate` is overlapping an existing leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: First you need to store user's value in temp variables like leavefrom value in a and leaveto value in b.

Step2: Now check validity by below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(empid) FROM employee WHERE ($a>=leavefrom AND $a<=leaveto) OR ($b=leavefrom AND $b<=leaveto) and empid=1;
```

Step3: If you are getting value >0 means requested leave is not valid else it is valid. If valid then you can insert in table otherwose throw message to user.